# Gitlab with Git LFS on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, git-lfs

Now that Gitlab announced [Git LFS support](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/23/announcing-git-lfs-support-in-gitlab/) I am asking if it is possible to store the Git LFS files on Amazon S3? I don't want to store the repositories itself just LFS files.

Comment: https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3 could help, maybe?

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed since the previous answer (2016). From [the same GitLab documentation link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/lfs/lfs_administration.html#storing-lfs-objects-in-remote-object-storage), if you host git repositories on your own GitLab server (not the gitlab.com), you can set up storage of LFS files on S3 or GCS.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

```
Currently, storing GitLab Git LFS objects on a non-local storage (like S3 buckets) is not supported
```

[GitLab LFS docs](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/lfs/lfs_administration.html)